# ProjectName.apk file not found while running game using AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I have added AndEngine library successfully and created my own game project. For first thing I have modified MainActivity class to display splash screen. There is no error in the project but when I run the same eclipse throws error in console like below,

Could not find ProName.apk!'

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Can you post a complete Logcat?

Comment: This got resolved, Is Library was checked in project Properties > Android 
Thanks.

Comment: You should convert your comment to an answer and expand on the explanation, so you can mark this question as answered.  Users who always accept answers on their questions are more likely to get help in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved,
If anybody facing the same problem do this as below,
- right click on your Project 
- Click on Properties
- Select Android from options in left pane of properties window
- Uncheck "Is Library" (if it is checked)
- Click Apply and Ok
- done :-)

Regards,
Deepak